# Why are my polygons being drawn in the wrong location?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, polygon

I am practicing C# basic WPF/XAML drawing for an assignment and right off the bat I cannot figure out why my polygons are being drawn in the wrong place.

My window is of 1280x720 fixed, non-resizeable. I am trying to programmatically create my polygons by:

1. Creating points in the coordinates I want them to be: 
   `

   - [0,0]
   - [max height, 0],
   - [max height, max width],
   - [0, max width],
   - [max height/2, max width/2]

`

2. Creating polygons that consists of three points each, [0,0] and two edges. My screen is supposed to be split into four triangles.

I tried breaking down the code to something really explicit to see if I could figure out where the issue is, so this is what I have:

```
private void CreatePolygons()
{ 
    List<Point> PointList = new List<Point>
    {
        new Point(MainUI.Height / 2, MainUI.Width / 2),
        new Point(0, 0),
        new Point(0, MainUI.Height),
        new Point(MainUI.Width, MainUI.Height),
        new Point(MainUI.Width, 0)                
    };

    Polygon p1 = new Polygon();
    Polygon p2 = new Polygon();
    Polygon p3 = new Polygon();
    Polygon p4 = new Polygon();

    p1.Points.Add(PointList[0]);
    p1.Points.Add(PointList[1]);
    p1.Points.Add(PointList[2]);

    p2.Points.Add(PointList[0]);
    p2.Points.Add(PointList[2]);
    p2.Points.Add(PointList[3]);

    p3.Points.Add(PointList[0]);
    p3.Points.Add(PointList[3]);
    p3.Points.Add(PointList[4]);

    p4.Points.Add(PointList[0]);
    p4.Points.Add(PointList[4]);
    p4.Points.Add(PointList[1]);

    p1.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSkyBlue;
    p2.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSkyBlue;
    p3.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSkyBlue;
    p4.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSkyBlue;

    p1.StrokeThickness = 1;
    p2.StrokeThickness = 1;
    p3.StrokeThickness = 1;
    p4.StrokeThickness = 1;

    MainGrid.Children.Add(p1);
    MainGrid.Children.Add(p2);
    MainGrid.Children.Add(p3);
    MainGrid.Children.Add(p4);
}
```

The end result is a completely misplaced grid and I can't understand what the coordinates it ended up creating refer to:

[image: Main grid]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You have accidentally swapped the `Width` and `Height` in the first point:

```
new Point(MainUI.Height / 2, MainUI.Width / 2),
```

Should be:

```
new Point(MainUI.Width / 2, MainUI.Height / 2),
```

Further, assuming `MainUI` is the app window itself, the points will still be a bit off, because the `Height` of the window **includes its title bar height**. You should better use `MainGrid.ActualWidth` and `MainGrid.ActualHeight`:

```
List<Point> PointList = new List<Point>
{
    new Point(MainGrid.ActualWidth / 2, MainGrid.ActualHeight / 2),
    new Point(0, 0),
    new Point(0, MainGrid.ActualHeight),
    new Point(MainGrid.ActualWidth, MainGrid.ActualHeight),
    new Point(MainGrid.ActualWidth, 0)
};
```

Comment: Using `ActualWidth` or `ActualHeight` instead of simply `Height` or `Width` causes it to not draw anything. I assumed it would be because my grid doesn't have a size defined, so I replaced by my Window's object instead and it doesn't draw anything either. Is there a reason to it? Also what are the advantages of using a Canvas for that matter, following the comment I got before?

Comment: Actually the reason is it is called too early - before the layout process takes place. Try attaching a `Loaded` event handler to your window and inside call the `CreatePolygons` method (or `SizeChanged` if you want to keep points in the right place when window size is changed, but you will need to remove the previous points before creating new ones)

Answer (score 1):

Besides that you have confused Width and Height of the first point, I'd suggest not to create UI elements like Polygons in code behind. Better use an ItemsControl like this:

```
<Grid SizeChanged="MainUISizeChanged">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="polygons">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Polygon Stroke="LightSkyBlue" StrokeThickness="1"
                         Points="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

and assign its ItemsSource property to a collection of PointCollections, e.g. whenever the size of your MainUI element changes:

```
private void MainUISizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var points = new List<Point>
    {
        new Point(e.NewSize.Width / 2, e.NewSize.Height / 2),
        new Point(0, 0),
        new Point(0, e.NewSize.Height),
        new Point(e.NewSize.Width, e.NewSize.Height),
        new Point(e.NewSize.Width, 0)
    };

    polygons.ItemsSource = new List<PointCollection>
    {
        new PointCollection(new Point[] { points[0], points[1], points[2] }),
        new PointCollection(new Point[] { points[0], points[2], points[3] }),
        new PointCollection(new Point[] { points[0], points[3], points[4] }),
        new PointCollection(new Point[] { points[0], points[4], points[1] }),
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to all the Polygon point calcuations, you may use this simple Path element, which produces the same output and stretches automatically:

```
<Grid>
    <Path Stretch="Fill" Stroke="LightSkyBlue" StrokeThickness="1"
          Data="M0,0 L1,0 1,1 0,1Z M0,0 L1,1 M0,1 L1,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I need them to be separate elements because of the way they will interact with another component. I believe I can't do that with a `Path` element since it's going to be a single entity

Comment: You may perhaps have multiple Paths to still benefit from their ability to stretch the Geometry in their Data.